How to fetch from cosmos db using LINQ records based on certain daterange?
I have a usecase where I need to fetch upcoming birthdays of customers for next 30 days.
We are storing the birthday as datetime in UTC format in cosmos records.
But when I try to fetch using the LINQ query, it doesn't seem to work.
How can we fetch date ranges like only take records which fall in a certain month ?
 DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
 var next30Days = today.AddDays(30);

var users= await _cosmosClient
    .GetByQuery(up => users.Contains(up.UserId) && up.Birthday.IsDefined() &&
    ((up.Birthday.Month == today.Month) ||
    (up.Birthday.Month == next30Days.Month) ||
    (up.Birthday.Month == today.AddMonths(1).Month)),
    pk);


GetBYQuery is wrapper for the actual LINQ Query
public async Task<FeedResponse<T>> GetByQuery(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> query, 
    PartitionKey partitionKey, 
    int limit = -1, 
    string continuationToken = null)
{
        var queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions()
        {
            PartitionKey = partitionKey,
            MaxItemCount = limit
        };

        using var iterator = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(
continuationToken: continuationToken, 
requestOptions: queryRequestOptions,
linqSerializerOptions: _linqSerializerOptions)
            .Where(query)
            .ToFeedIterator();

        var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
        return response;    
}


Are you getting any error?

No errors. Just doesn’t fetch any record

What I ended up doing was to write the SQL with datepart logic
var query = new QueryDefinition(
            "SELECT * FROM c WHERE (DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) = @todayMonth AND DateTimePart('dd', c.birthday) >= @todayDay) " +
            "OR (DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) = @next30DaysMonth AND DateTimePart('dd', c.birthday) <= @next30DaysDay) " +
            "OR (DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) > @todayMonth AND DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) < @next30DaysMonth) " +
            "OR (@todayMonth > @next30DaysMonth AND " +
            "((DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) > @todayMonth OR (DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) = @todayMonth AND DateTimePart('dd', c.birthday) >= @todayDay)) " +
            "OR (DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) < @next30DaysMonth OR (DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) = @next30DaysMonth AND DateTimePart('dd', c.birthday) <= @next30DaysDay))))")
            .WithParameter("@todayMonth", today.Month)
            .WithParameter("@todayDay", today.Day)
            .WithParameter("@next30DaysMonth", next30Days.Month)
            .WithParameter("@next30DaysDay", next30Days.Day);


DateTimePart('mm', c.birthday) works in SQL. I am guessing the LINQ version doesnt get translated into this and hence fails
